# How to import extension reviews from Magento Connect to my store for same extension?

Tags: import, magento-connect, review

I have a Magento online store which sells magento extensions and I have also put my extensions on Magento Connect. I want import reviews given by customers on Magento Connect on my store. Is there any API or Code snippet available for this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have contacted to Magento Connect regarding this and here is their reply:

“Thank you for contacting us. Unfortunately, we do not have an recommendation for this it is best that you have a link to the reviews.”

Answer (score 0):

- Goto https://www.magentocommerce.com/
- Create magento account.
- and them Login
- click developer menu.
- and them go to as per suggestion.